# How to check whether a Button is clicked by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there a simple way to do something along these lines:

JavaScript:

```
if(document.getElementById('button').clicked == true)
{
   alert("button was clicked");
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="enter"/>
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can add a click event handler for this:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
   alert("button was clicked");
}​;​
```

This will alert when it's clicked, if you want to track it for later, just set a variable to true in that function instead of alerting, or `variable++` if you want to count the number of clicks, whatever your ultimate use is.  [You can see an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/6qDap/1/).

Comment: Note that setting onclick will overwrite existing event listeners, so it is probably better to use addEventListener here, as I outlined below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57811342/10965456)

Answer (score 19):

Try adding an event listener for clicks:

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
   alert("You clicked me");
}​);​
```

Using `addEventListener` is probably a better idea then setting `onclick` - `onclick` can easily be overwritten by another piece of code.

You can use a variable to store whether or not the button has been clicked before:

```
var clicked = false
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
   clicked = true
}​);​
```

[addEventListener on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer instead of the accepted one

Answer (score 5):

This will do it

```
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" onclick="myFunction();" value="enter"/>

<script>
function myFunction(){
    alert("The button was pressed");
};   
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

All the answers here discuss about onclick method, however you can also use addEventListener().

Syntax of addEventListener()

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click",{function defination});
```

The function defination above is known as anonymous function.

If you don't want to use anonymous functions you can also use function refrence.

```
function functionName(){
//function defination
}



document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click",functionName);
```

You can check the detail differences between onclick() and addEventListener() in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick).

Comment: I think you missed one... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57811342/10965456

Answer (score 2):

Just hook up the onclick event:

```
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="enter" onclick="myFunction();"/>
```

Comment: Please don't use in-line handlers, [there are so many reasons not to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479557/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-use-links-with-the-javascript-protocol/2479582#2479582).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#button").on('click',function(){
//do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function check() { 
    console.log("Button Clicked");
};

var button= document.querySelector("button"); // Accessing The Button // 
button.addEventListener("click", check); // Adding event to call function when clicked //
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like  this:

```
<button onClick="funtion()">Button Goes Here</button
```

```js
function alert(){
console.log('Alert Showed');
alert('You clicked me!');
}
```

```html
<button onClick="alert()">Click me to get alerted</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("button was clicked");
})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this event listener will help you detect clicks on the document
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){   
// <event>.<target>.<id> check that the id is 'button'
if(e.target.id === 'button'){
    // do something here 
    console.log(e.target.id); 
}
```

}