# How to check if a button has been clicked using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Here i need to check a button click using javascript i.e)if button A is clicked i will call a javascript function and if button B is clicked i will call another javascript function.

```
if(document.getElementById('imgBTNExportPPT').clicked == true)
{
   ShowDialogExportPPTPOPUP();
}
else if(document.getElementById('btnShowModal').clicked == true)
{
   ShowDialogPrintPOPUP();
}
```

and

```
      <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBTNExportPPT" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" border="0"
                                                            OnClick="imgBTNExportPPT_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/PPT_icon.png" />
  <asp:ImageButton ID="btnShowModal" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" border="0"
                                                         ImageUrl="~/Images/Print_icon.png" onclick="btnShowModal_Click"  />
```

is it possible??any suggestion??

Comment: take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788191/is-there-a-way-to-use-javascript-to-check-if-a-button-has-been-clicked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
function buttonClicked(choice)
{
   if(choice == 'A')
   {
      ShowDialogExportPPTPOPUP();
   }
   else if(choice ==  'B')
   {
      ShowDialogPrintPOPUP();
   }
}
```

HTML code should be like this :

```
<input type='button' value='ButtonA' onclick="buttonClicked('A')" />
<input type='button' value='ButtonB' onclick="buttonClicked('B')" />
```

If it's a server side control then you can do it in two ways :

```
  <asp:ImageButton onClientClick="buttonClicked('A')" ID="imgBTNExportPPT" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" border="0"
                                                            OnClick="imgBTNExportPPT_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/PPT_icon.png" />
  <asp:ImageButton onClientClick="buttonClicked('A')" ID="btnShowModal" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" border="0"
                                                         ImageUrl="~/Images/Print_icon.png" onclick="btnShowModal_Click"  />
```

OR (in C#)

```
{
 imgBTNExportPPT.Attributes.Add("onclick", "buttonClicked('A')");
 btnShowModal.Attributes.Add("onclick", "buttonClicked('B')");
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: :its an asp button control then i have to call this one in onclientclick??

Answer (score 3):

You have to use OnClientClick attribute of ImageButton to assign javascript function. You can pass this in javascript call to get the button object being clicked.

*OnClientClick="TestClick('A', this);"* add this in button

**In .aspx Page**

```
<asp:ImageButton OnClientClick="TestClick('A', this);" ID="imgBTNExportPPT" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" border="0"                                                                  OnClick="imgBTNExportPPT_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/PPT_icon.png"  />

<asp:ImageButton OnClientClick="TestClick('B', this);" ID="btnShowModal" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" border="0"
                                                                 ImageUrl="~/Images/Print_icon.png" onclick="btnShowModal_Click"  />
```

**In Script**

```
function TestClick(choice, btnClicked)
{
   alert(btnClicked.id + " clicked");
   if(choice == 'A')
   {
      ShowDialogExportPPTPOPUP();
   }
   else if(choice ==  'B')
   {
      ShowDialogPrintPOPUP();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add an identifier or just call a function in the onclick event. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onButtonClick(button)
    { 
        alert("button " + button + " clicked!"); 
    }
</script>

<button id="ButtonA" onclick="javascript:onButtonClick('buttonA'); return false;" />
<button id="ButtonB" onclick="javascript:onButtonClick('buttonB'); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good example. Transfer your code as the callback to `runOnce` and create an onclick event handler like the one below to restrict your function to one call:

```
function runOnce( callback ) {

  var done = false;

  return function() {

    if ( !done ) {
      done = true;

      callback();

    }

  };

}

var one = runOnce(function() {
    alert('Once');
}),
    two = runOnce(function() {
    alert('Once only too.');
});

document.getElementById('first').onclick = one;
document.getElementById('second').onclick = two;
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5nvCX/)