# Javascript : Url Redirection after form submission

Tags: javascript

I have the following newsletter Mailchimp form:

```
<div class="mc4wp-form-fields"><p>
    <label>Email: 
        <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="" required="">
</label>
</p>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</p></div>
```

I need when someone clicks on the subscribe button, after 2 seconds to redirect in a new URL in a new tab. For example [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)

How is this possible to happen using javascript?

Comment: `window.location = "www.youtube.com"` will work perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your button with following code, then put myFunction() function code in your file.

```
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" onclick="myFunction();" value="Subscribe"/>


<script>
function myFunction(){
    setTimeout(function () { window.location = "www.youtube.com" }, 2000);
};   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect the click of a button, use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788191/how-to-check-whether-a-button-is-clicked-by-using-javascript). Then, to redirect the user after X seconds, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150171/page-redirect-after-x-seconds-wait-using-javascript).

Comment: Im new to javascript, Can you please write the exact code? the sumit button its <input> type, not a class.

Comment: Try this: https://codepen.io/Modz_/pen/KKqKxVX. It's supposed to work, if it doesn't report it to me, I'll try directly with a HTML page

Answer (score 0):

For your subscribe button, you can do this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" onclick="subscribe()"/*executes a command on click*/>
```

When you do this, you get the button to reference a javascript function.

Now, you can include the javascript function.

```
function subscribe(){
    setTimeout(function () {
          location.replace("https://youtube.com")/*replaces the website with youtube.com*/
    }
}, 2000 /*waits for 2000 miliseconds(2 seconds) before executing code in setTimeout*/);
```

Here it is in live code.

```js
function subscribe() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.replace("https://youtube.com")/*replaces the website with youtube.com*/
  }, 2000 /*waits for 2000 miliseconds(2 seconds) before executing code in setTimeout*/ );
}
```

```html
<div class="mc4wp-form-fields"><p>
    <label>Email: 
        <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="" required="">
</label>
</p>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" onclick="subscribe()" /*executes a 
command on click*/>
</p></div>
```