# Invoking jQuery function without an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

So, I use jQuery quite extensively and I am well aware of the "right" way to do the below, but there are times where I want to solve it in a more generic way. I'll explain.

So, I may have a link, like this: `<a href='menu' class='popup'>Show menu</a>`. Now, I have a jQuery function that fires on click for all a.popup that takes the href-attribute and shows the `<div id='menu'></div>` item (in this case). It also handles URL's if it can't find a DOM item with that ID.

No problem here. But, there are times when I don't have the same control over the coe where I can create a selectable target that way. Either because the code isn't created by me or because it is created through a chain of function that would all need a huge ovrhaul which I won't do.

So, from time to time, I would like to have this code:

```
<a href="javascript:popup('menu')">Show menu</a>
```

This would be in a case where I can only submit the label and the HREF for a link. No class, no nothing.

Problem here is that the function popup() has no idea about what element invoked it, and in most cases that's not a problem for me, since I only need to know where the mouse cursor was upon invokation.

But in some cases, I use someone elses jQuery functions, like qTip or something else. so I still want to fire off qTip(); when clicking a link that runs this JS function, but what do I attach it to to make it show? I can't just runt $().qTip(); because that implies $(this) and "this" is undefined inside the function.

So how do I do it? Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479557/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-use-links-with-the-javascript-protocol

Comment: you need to put markup in `<code>` or indent it with four spaces to avoid it being rendered as HTML

Comment: My apologies, Sean. And Crescent - that really didn't help at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anyway you change the javascript method to `javascript:popup('menu', this);`? I've used this method successfully many times.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, but when I tried it, the "this" never did seem to point to the A tag. I'll try it again and have a look.

Comment: @Sandman: again, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479557/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-use-links-with-the-javascript-protocol  `this` is meaningless when used inside `href="javascript:..."`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. I get an error even when using it as onclick=""... but that could be for some other reason. I know of the difference between onclick and javascript: and the system actually translates javascript: to onclick on the fly, so my examples would actually become onclicks :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of referring to "`this`" try referring to `$('a:focus')` to refer to the link that was clicked.

Here's a quick and, as @Crescent Fresh would add, dirty (☺) sample:

```
<body>
<p><a href="javascript:popup('menu')">Show popup()</a></p>
<div id="menu" style="display:none">Today's menu</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function popup(elm) {
    $('#' + elm).show();
    alert( $('a:focus').text() )
}
</script>
</body>
```

I tried just "`:focus`" but IE7 returned too much content. I tested this in FF 3.6.3, IE7, Chrome 4.1.249.1064 (all on Windows) and it seems OK, but I see now (when I was just about to hit "Post Your Answer") this relies on the browser's native support for `querySelectorAll` - see this jQuery Forum post "[:focus selector filter?](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/focus-selector-filter)" and the [jQuery.expr entry in the jQuery Source Viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4&fn=expr) (where it appears Paul's idea was not implemented).

Comment: Interesting. It would probably mess upp bested links (which is invalid anyway) and wouldn't work if the onclick="" handler is added to anything but a link. It could be a fallbak if the popup() function fails to find a "this". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
<a href="javascript:popup(event, 'menu')">Show menu</a>
```

Once you get the event object you can virtually do anything to it.