# is it bad practice to use href='javascript:func()' than onclick='func()' for anchors?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Href for Javascript links: “#” or “javascript:void(0)”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)
>   [Why is it bad practice to use links with the javascript: “protocol”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479557/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-use-links-with-the-javascript-protocol)

As question says . .

Which approach is better ?

```
<a href='javascript:func()' >blah</a>
```

or

```
<a href='#' onclick='func()' >blah</a>
```

Comment: Better for what? Maintainability? Browser compatibility? Something else?

Comment: I'm interested in this answer too. I would say from a compatibility standpoint, primarily.

Comment: @Oded if you can define form both point of view(or any other point of view) .. then it will very good thing to know .

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither.

Use this:

```
<a href="javascript-disabled-page" onclick="func(); return false;">blah</a>
```

That way if the user has JS disabled, they will be taken to `javascript-disabled-page` and the browsing experience isn't ruined.

Comment: +1 for suggesting javascript-disabled-page .

Comment: still better: add the event handler from javascript itself. still +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you want to achieve. From a SEO perspective it's better to use links only for actual links, and use click events on other tags for things that doesn't navigate anywhere:

```
<span class="LinkLookalike" onclick="func();">blah</span>
```

Comment: SEO has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Coronatus: SEO is mainly about *content* and *links*, and now you say that SEO has *nothing* to do with links? Perhaps you should tell Google about this revolutionary change...

Comment: SEO is about content and links ("mainly" isn't reliably true). In this case the links and SEO have nothing to do with each other because search spiders can't execute Javascript and would need to be incredibly dumb (which none are) to not deal with this common usage.

Comment: From an accessibility standpoint, I would not use `<span/>` unless you have an explicit `taborder` attribute because it cannot otherwise receive `focus()`. Perhaps use `<button/>`?