# Javascript function call with arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a mobile application using phonegap and jquery mobile. I have this function which has to pass a variable to another function. It goes something like this:

```
    $.each(response.records, function(i, contact) {
       var url = contact.Id;
       var newLi = $("<li><a href='javascript:dothis("+url+")'>" + (i+1) + " - " + contact.Name + " - Company "+contact.Company+"</a></li>");
           ul.append(newLi);}
```

I have the dothis(argument) function but it does not get called when i put in the variable "url". When i erase the argument, it works. Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the url in quotes in the javascript:

```
var newLi = $("<li><a href=\"javascript:dothis('" +
      url +
      "')\">" + 
      (i+1) + " - " + contact.Name + 
      " - Company " + contact.Company + "</a></li>");
```

You *might* need to consider escaping the URL so that, if it contains any difficult characters, your javascript won't break.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely not good practice to use the `javascript:` protocol in `href` attributes. It's much better to bind events to the links and respond accordingly.

Insert something like this after you append `newLi` to the ul:

```
$.find('a').bind('click', function() {
    dothis(url);
});
```

Here's some more info about why it's bad practice to use the `javascript:` protocol:
[Why is it bad practice to use links with the javascript: "protocol"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479557/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-use-links-with-the-javascript-protocol)

Comment: thanks Philip Walton. I guess i was going for the 1990's thing :(