# onclick="javascript:func()" vs. onclick="func()"

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="javascript:submitTheForm();">
```

and

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="submitTheForm();">
```

Should I use `javascript:` before a JS function call?

Comment: on***** runs javascript without defining them a "javascript:"

Comment: either way, it's not good practice to use inline

Comment: Thanks! I know about handlers, just doubt about this case :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`javascript:` inside an `onwhatever=""` handler is a no-op. The content of this attribute is always JavaScript so `javascript:` defines a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) - but outside of a `switch` block or a loop (where you can use it to `break`/`continue` to the position of the label) it does nothing.

However, using inline event handlers is discouraged, there are [better](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) [ways](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to register event handlers.

---

While not mentioned in the question, it's worth noting that using `javascript:` in the `href` attribute does work (and in there it is actually necessary) but is highly discouraged for various reasons:

- `this` does not point to the element
- Calling a function returning a value causes the browser to leave the site
- Clicking the link with disabled JavaScript breaks
- Trying to open the link in a new window/tab breaks

So, if you really have to use inline events, always use `onclick=""` etc. without `javascript:`.

Comment: You can use it also with `break` and any statement. It does not have to be used together with `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in a `onclick` attribute, you shouldn't use the `javascript:` prefix. This is usefull when you want a link `<a />` to handle a JS function, for example:

```
<a href="javascript:myfunc();"></a>
```

Comment: `javascript:` URLs are bad. Not only do they break with disabled JavaScript but they also cause problems if the function returns a value. So better use a proper URL in the `href` (or `#` if the link does not have a non-js fallback) and `onclick` to run your javascript code (`return false;`/`preventDefault` to avoid loading the href of the link)

Comment: I agree with you. The question was about the `javascript:` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

`javascript:func()` is using the [javascript protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767736%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) so that it could be used in an anchors `href` attribute. However, don't do this see [Why is it bad practice to use links with the javascript: “protocol”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2479557/540765) for more information.

Event handlers are preferable to trigger events instead of attributes.

Comment: The OP asked about `onclick`, not about `href`

Comment: Anyway thanks about the related question!

Comment: @ThiefMaster - true but he was also asking about script starting with `javascript:`.