# Difference between remove() and detach() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question related to jQuery `.remove()` method. Consider this code:

```
var x;
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    x = $("p").remove();
});
$("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("body").prepend(x);
});
```

If the code is checked on click on the button2, the paragraph element is restored. 
I heard that `remove()` and `detach()` methods are different. How can they be different when `remove()` itself keeps all jQuery data?

Comment: These are two completely unrelated questions. Please open a separate one for each. Also, the first one needs more detail. What exactly do you want to know about the `javascript:` keyword.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: @Philipp if u can answer this plz help me.That's  what i needed

Comment: "javascript:" is not a keyword; it's a URL scheme and generally in 2013 its use is an indication of bad programming practice.

Comment: @MaizerePathak I will answer you after you did what I told you to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is "javascript:" used for, and is it compliant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933863/what-is-javascript-used-for-and-is-it-compliant)

Comment: @Pointy — Except when it is a label (when it is an indication of cargo cultism).

Comment: So... you decided to remove the first part of the question.

Comment: @Quentin yes but it's not a "keyword".  And I think using "javascript:" as a label is at least kind-of weird :-)

Comment: @FelixKling i need answer plz

Comment: @Pointy — Nor is it a URL scheme :) It's cargo cultism. "I have seen people use this in `href` therefore I must use it in `onclick` even though I don't understand why it is used in `href`" this of course leads to "I have seen people use it in `onclick` therefore I must etc etc" :)

Comment: Well, Esailija answered.

Comment: Thank you for editing this into a single question. I made a couple of small further changes, and voted to reopen.

Comment: @Quentin u closed my question even after i have edited why?why did u do this?

Comment: @MaizerePathak — I voted to close it before you edited it. That's why my name is at the front.

Comment: @epascarello plz vote to reopen as i have edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.remove()` removes the jQuery internal data about the contained elements from `jQuery.cache` . Such data includes custom data set with `.data()` and the data required by jQuery's event model.

`.detach()` does not remove that data.

`.remove()/.detach()` additionally just remove the element(s) from the DOM tree. It's like removing an item from an array... the item itself does not just magically vanish even if it's no longer in the array. Especially if you keep a reference to it like you are doing in your code.

Comment: i edited my post and i got it closed why?

Comment: @MaizerePathak It was closed before you edited (because it had two unrelated questions in a single post). Now it may be reopened. Try to comment to some of the people above, mentioning their usernames with @, maybe they'll vote to reopen too.