# What is the difference between onclick=a(); and javascript:onclick="a();" in inline JavaScript calls?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [When do I need to specify the JavaScript protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321469/when-do-i-need-to-specify-the-javascript-protocol)
> [onclick=“javascript:func()” vs. onclick=“func()”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242576/onclick-javascriptfunc-vs-onclick-func)

What exactly is the difference between the two code examples below?

1. `<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="a()">`

   and
2. `<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="javascript:a()">`

   Where `a()` is any JavaScript function.

Comment: Using `javascript:` there has the same effect as using `foobar:`: None.

Comment: Both are equally bad practice and old fashioned

Comment: The only case where it is *necessary* is when you make a bookmarklet, in which case, by default, `http` is assumed as the protocol, which you might not want.

Comment: @Cthulhu: It's never necessary in inline event handlers. You were probably thinking about `a` elements and the `href` value.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, I said above that it was necessary esp. when making URLs for *bookmarks*, in which it is automatically assumed to be an `http` URI when devoid of protocol. in inline event handlers, unnecessary, agreed.