# Capturing the anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, overriding

I've written a JavaScript code which over-ride the native alert() method.
I need to capture the HTML element which comprises the code of alert() execution.
First two cases are examples. I have printed the elements in console.log.

**Case 1 - Capturing the `<script>` tag:**

*HTML:* `<script> alert(1); </script>`

*JS:*

```
window.alert = function()
{ 
    console.log(document.currentScript); // <script> is printed
}
```

**Case 2  - Capturing the `<img>` tag:**

*HTML:* `<img src='1' onerror="alert(1)">`

*JS:*

```
window.alert = function()
{ 
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0].target);
    // arguments.callee --> console.log()
    // arguments.callee.caller --> onerror(event) {}
    // arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0] --> event
    // arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0].target --> <img>
}
```

**Case issue - Capturing the `<a>` tag:**

*HTML:* `<a href="javascript:alert(1);">Click here for alert</a>`

*JS:*

```
window.alert = function()
{ 
    console.log( // how to find <a> element) 
}
```

Please don't suggest me to modify the HTML by including IDs for `<a>` or something similar. Consider that the HTML is purely static, and I can't modify anything. I can just add a JavaScript, and I just wan't to know how this can be done.

Comment: You can do similar thing. The only difference is that the click on anchor load new page (as a rule). Check "Preserve log" checkbox in Google Dev Tools to see messages from previous pages.

Comment: _"Please don't suggest me to modify the HTML"_, _"Consider that the HTML is purely static, and I can't modify anything."_ How can  `<a>` element be clicked where element does not contain `html` or text content to click `<a href="javascript:alert(1);"></a>`?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev No no, the application will be running in the client side. I need to find the `<a>` element only using JS and send necessary data to server from client.

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry, missed that thing to be clicked. Edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to find such alerts and convert them to click events.  Something like this.  Note the click event alert call could be made much more sophisticated and potentially use eval(), but i leave that for you to risk.

```js
window.alert = (function(){
  var selected = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='javascript:alert('");

  Array.from(selected).forEach(function(item){
    var old = item.href
    item.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert(old.substring(11)); });
    item.href="javascript:void(0);";
  });

  var _alert = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0].target);
  };
  
  return _alert;
})();
```

```html
<a href="javascript:alert(1);">test</a>
```

Comment: +1 This helped. Thanks. Is there any more simplistic solution? Like, traversing from alert() to href, and href to `<a>`? Something similar? And, I don't get eval() thing you've mentioned. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It might be possible to parse the alert( ***--- parse this ---*** ) so that you might do something with the request such as console.log() it.  A basic parsing would log the text of the call and would work ok for translating alert("hi"), but you could potentially also use eval() to handle alter(1+1).  Eval can be a bit dangerous so, I tend to shy away from it myself but it might be something you could leverage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `load` event at `window`; `click` event at selector `"a[href='javascript:alert(1);']"` to get value of `href` attribute; call `event.preventDefault()` within `click` handler; `String.prototype.match()` to create array of values withing `href` attribute; define matches globally; `new Function()`; `Function.prototype.call()` to set `this` to `<a>` element; call `.click()` on selector : `<a>` element with matched parameters returned by `.match()`

```js
window.alert = function() {
  console.log(arguments, this)
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {

  a = document.querySelector("a[href='javascript:alert(1);']");
  a.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = this.href.replace(/javascript/, "");
    matches = data.match(/\w+(?=\()|(\(.*\))/g);
    matches[1] = matches[1].replace(/\(|\)/g, "");
    var fn = new Function(matches[0] + ".call(a, matches[1])");
    fn();
  });

  a.click();

});
```

```html
<a href="javascript:alert(1);"></a>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. But, this doesn't suit for generic finding. I mean, there can be anything in the HTML - alert(1), alert('anything'), [all kind of pop-ups] I need a common solution for all, similar to case 1 and 2.

Comment: @unix_root _"But, this doesn't suit for generic finding. I mean, there can be anything in the HTML - alert(1), alert('anything'),"_ Which case does not return expected result using `RegExp` `/\(|\)/g` ?

Comment: Can you please add some documentation to the Regexp code? I don't get it.

Comment: @unix_root The first `RegExp` replaces `javascript` with empty string; second `RegExp` attempts to capture function name by matching word followed by `(`,  and function parameters `(1)`, including parenthesis; third `RegExp` replaces parenthesis at second captured group, function parameters, with empty string;  parameter `1` is set as replacement string  value of `matches[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the href attribute to call JavaScript. It should be avoided. It is not recommended usage. Use the onclick event instead. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10242595/5969411

```
<script>
    window.alert = function(msg, element) {
        console.log('Msg:', msg);
        console.log('Element:', element);
    };
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="alert(1, this);return false;">Test 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="alert(2, this);return false;">Test 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="alert(3, this);return false;">Test 3</a>
```

I've returned false from the onclick event above in order to repress the anchor from going to '#' URL directive, but you could easily return true instead here, if you wish.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But, this comes under case 2 - using events. I need some sort of solution for exact case given in the question.