# ID trigger not working in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div ID that triggers some javascript. It works fine outside of the innerHTML, but when I try to only have it trigger when the div ID is clicked (while in the innerHTML) it does not trigger.

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ChangeStyle()
{
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = 
        "<div id='12345' class='button next' class='move next'><a href=\"javascript:void()\">CONFIRM </a></div>";
}

</script>
<span id="p1">
<div class="button"><a href="javascript:void()"     onclick="ChangeStyle();alert('hello');">CONFIRM  </a></div></a>
</span>
```

Comment: The above code works for me on jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/rk58c/. (Yes I have removed `javascript:void()` and added `return:false` but that's just because it's bad practice).

Comment: @HenrikAmmer Since when is `javascript:void()` bad practice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: @ianpgall, that question is from 2008... read [SO: Why is it bad practice to use links with the javascript: “protocol”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479557/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-use-links-with-the-javascript-protocol) and also the last line of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Comment: Why does your `<span>` has a `<div>` as its `innerHTML` ? `<span>` is an inline element, `<div>` is a block-level element.

Comment: I changed to <span> and still my id does not trigger the javascript.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Unfortunately, technically the "best" practice is not to use a link for this kind of behavior. I highly doubt the OP or anyone who uses links really wants the browser to direct the user to a real page if Javascript is disabled. If the user doesn't want the page to work if Javascript is disabled, then that's their preference...it's not necessarily "better" for them to waste time unobtrusifying it.

Comment: @ianpgall, unobtrusive javascript is not for the case of disabled javascript in browser (*you might be confusing it with progressive enhancement*). It is for seperation of concerns.. HTML for markup of content, CSS for styling, JS for behavior. you can always use `#` and `return false` from the `onclick` handler.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Ahh I see. Nonetheless, if unobtrusive is really being suggested, then it seems like they shouldn't have any `onclick` attribute, and should bind it up in a DOM ready event, and shouldn't have `javascript:void(0)` nor `#` and `return false;`

Comment: @ianpgall, true.. that would be the *proper* way ..

Answer (score 3):

You're adding the `class` property twice, the one value will always override the other. Combine them into one property, and your code will be working:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RuKmj/)

However, if all you want to do is to change the class, you can set the `className` property of your element.

```
div.className = 'button next move';
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KSKmU/)

Comment: my class is not the issue that not triggering it is my "id". if I copy that same html I have in innerHTML and place it outside of the innerHTML code and post as normal, it triggers the javascript. but inside the innerHTML it does not trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `javascript:void()` to `javascript:void(0)`

The above `class` argument also holds correct.

Answer (score -1):

If all you're trying to do is add a class then can you use

```
$('div .button).addClass('next');
```

Comment: This isn't a jQuery question.