# The column header Hide isn't being displayed in firefox in an iis application

Tags: java, javascript

```
<TABLE align='center' BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=4 CELLSPACING=0 CLASS=cTable>
   <TR>
      <th CLASS=TH1 align='center' valign='top' colspan='15'>Input Summary</th>
      <th CLASS=TH1 align='center' valign='top'>
         <style type="text/css">
            .myLayersClass { position: relative; display:none; }
         </style>
         <span id='spanHideSummary' class='myLayersClass' style='display:none'>
            <a href='javascript:ToggleDisplay("spanSummary", "");javascript:ToggleDisplay("spanPPDates", "TsLinks");'>Hide</a>
         </span>
      </th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And it should not be shown. According to `display:none` in `.myLayersClass` and [`style='display:none'`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) on span element. In order to fix it you should do something like this:

```
<th CLASS=TH1 align='center' valign='top'>
         <style type="text/css">
            .myLayersClass { position: relative;  }
         </style>
         <span id='spanHideSummary' class='myLayersClass'>
            <a href='javascript:ToggleDisplay("spanSummary", "");javascript:ToggleDisplay("spanPPDates", "TsLinks");'>Hide</a>
         </span>
      </th>
```

Besides, `javascript:...` in href is [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2479557/1558311). There is `onclick` event. It is better to do something like this (well, even that is not the best solution):

```
<a href='#' onclick="ToggleDisplay('spanSummary', ''; ToggleDisplay('spanPPDates', 'TsLinks'); return false;'>Hide</a>
```

Also, styles are better being located inside header tag. Suppose the main reason will be here that it will force browser to redraw everything just it will find your css in `<th>` and it is much easier to support a website which has all css in some predefined location (in `<head>` like inline styles or in css files).

Comment: But then why does it show in IE?

Comment: Suppose IE does not understand something in your code. Let me check how it works in IE.

Comment: Hm. I'm looking at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YygM8/) in IE7/8 and I do not see Hide there too. And that IS correct behavior (`display:none`, remember?). Maybe there is something else in your code not reflected in question which breaks IE somehow. Hard to say.

Comment: Weird. When I removed those 2 items it is now not showing in IE?

Comment: Never mind I got it. There was something else in the code that shows it if it was IE. I removed that check and now it displays for FF