# Enable scroll bar for my Nav Bar Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a navigation bar for my website with some dropdown at hover content. However, it seems that scrolling is disabled for them and I have tried many ways but failed to enable the scrollbar. Since the dropdown content is quite long I would like the scrollbar to **only** appear when the resolution or window size is small.

CSS(Not full, I didn't put most the parts regarding the styles):

```css
ul.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  z-index: 5;
}

ul.nav li a:hover:(.active), .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #760808;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #830303;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 50;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="homepage.html">Homepage</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0" class="dropbtn">a</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a><a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0" class="dropbtn">be</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0" class="dropbtn">c</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="../d.html">d</a></li>
  <li><a href="../e.html">e</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your missing a closing parenthesis on each inline javscript call

Comment: As far as I know `ul.nav li a:hover:(.active)` is invalid css. Should be `ul.nav li a.active:hover`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm kinda new to coding. Would you mind giving some explanations on that?

Comment: Are you using javascript for the dropdown? If so could you include it in the question

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake there, the code was actually     ul.nav li a:hover:(.active),
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #760808;
} I edited it.

Comment: I didn't use javascript for the dropdown, all the codes I used are Css and html. I do accept js if it is the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-content {
   max-height: 240px; /* or any other value you want */
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

But do note your current `href` expressions are invalid. Should be

```
href="javascript:void(0)"
```

(you need to close the paranthesis).

```js
$('.dropdown').on('mouseenter', function(e){
  $('.dropdown-content', this).show();
}).on('mouseleave', function(e){
  $('.dropdown-content', this).hide();
})
```

```css
ul.nav {
  display: flex;
}
ul.nav li {
  display: block;
}
ul.nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  z-index: 5;
}

ul.nav li a:hover:(.active), .dropdown:hover .dropbtn { 
  background-color: #760808;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #830303;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 50;
  max-height: 240px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="homepage.html">Homepage</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">a</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a><a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">be</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">c</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="../d.html">d</a></li>
  <li><a href="../e.html">e</a></li>
</ul>
```

You might also be interested in reading  why using javascript in href's is considered bad practice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479557/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-use-links-with-the-javascript-protocol) and it's accepted answer.

Which is to say: returning `void(0)`  works, but if you ever get tempted to use other javascript expressions in hrefs you'll probably forget the context is different, which will lead to subtle errors and unexpected behavior for your apps.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some errors in your css and inline javascript:

```
//JAVASCRIPT
href="javascript:void(0)"

//CSS
ul.nav li a.active:hover{}
```

I can't really recreate your issue based on the code you provided. However, for the problem that you are facing you will need to look into the `overflow-y` property in css. Particularly you would want to set that property to `scroll` Such as `overflow-y:scroll` for each element that you would like to add a vertical scrollbar too. Similarly if you would like a horizontal scroll bar then set `overflow-x:scroll`.

As far as window size is concerned you will need to use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) for a css only solution. There is a lot of information on media queries and how they work and you will need to figure out what works for your application. This is an example of what it may look like:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .dropdown-content {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        /* Optionally: "overflow-y: auto;" */
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

If you are designing your website for view on small screens like touchscreen devices, there is no `hover` event for those devices, `hover` is in effect like `on click` or `on focus`. So please be mindful with using hover and designing for mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll look into it.