# Dont call 2nd method if 1st Method returns false in Javascript

Tags: javascript

But when date is not 15, then it calls both methods.
How can i make sure that if 1st method returns false then other method should not be called.

Below is the code,

```
<input type="text" id="txtDate" name="SelectedDate" onchange="javascript:myMethod1(); javascript:myMethod2();" />

<script>
function myMethod1(){
            var dateVal = new Date(document.getElementById("txtDate").value);               
            var dateday = dateVal.getDate();

            if(dateday != 15){                  
                document.getElementById("mySpan1").innerHTML = "Error Message";
                return false

            }else{                  
                return true;            
            }
        }

        function myMethod2(){               
            document.getElementById("mySpan2").innerHTML = "No Error";          
        }
  </script>
```

Comment: so, what do you want exactly?

Comment: @Tomasz - When date is not 15, then method1() returns false, so i dont want method2() to be called.

Comment: You need to share how you are calling else I see @Estradiaz code will do the job for you.

Comment: why don't you merge 2 methods to one?

Comment: he means in onchange

Comment: That is not an option..cannot merge the 2 methods. In actual code, i would be passing different arguments to each method on the onchange event.

Comment: function issueIsAFunctionThatDoesThis(argsFunc1, argsFunc2){return myMethod1(...argsFunc1) && myMethod2(...argsFunc2)}?

Comment: `if (myMethod1()) { myMethod2(); }`

Comment: A simple solution is to add onchange="javascript:if(myMethod1()) {myMethod2()}". Or add a third function which contains if(myMethod1()) {myMethod2()

Comment: its easy all you need to do is call myMethod1() onchange and if it returns true then you can call myMethod2() from myMethod1() body

Comment: Another case where inline JS is not the best option.

Comment: @Greg - I tried your solution,onchange="javascript:if(myMethod1()) {myMethod2()}". But this also does not work.

Comment: [Don't use inline event handler attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941483/1048572), and [don't use `javascript:` urls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2479557/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi - Its a legacy application, so i cannot change it. Just have to go with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nobody mentioned the most obvious and most used solution. You can use the short-circuit AND (`&&`) operator.

The short-circuit AND operator evaluate the right side only if the left side evaluated as `true` (or truthy). If on the right side there's a function call, that function will be called only if the left side evaluated as true:

```
(true && f()) // f will be called
(false && f()) // f will NOT be called
```

You can substitute `true` and `false` literals with other function calls.

In your specific case, you just need to substitute the semicolon with a *double and*:

```
onchange="javascript:(myMethod1() && myMethod2())"
```

```js
function f1() {
  console.log('f1 called');
  return Math.random() < 0.5;
}

function f2() {
  console.log('f2 called');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="javascript:(f1() && f2())">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Cristian. It worked like a charm. Just one issue is there. First time when the date is not 15, then it works. Then when i select other date then the Span2 is populated. then when i select date as 15 again, then both the messages can be seen. How can we resolve this ?

Comment: @RohitT the logic of your function could be wrong. This is another type of question unrelated to the solution that I provided, I advise you to use a debugger to understand where the problem is and, after that, if you still have problems then ask a new question

Comment: Was able to resolve the issue by making the other spans blank in the if  conditions of both the methods. - @Cristian

Answer (score 0):

How about this???

```
var shouldExecuteNext = function1();

if(!shouldExecuteNext){
function2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you calling both function at the same time if you dont want to execute them simultaneously. if you want to execute the 2nd method only when the 1st one returns true then try to call the 2nd method inside the 1st method in else block where you return true like this:

```
<input type="text" id="txtDate" name="SelectedDate" onchange="javascript:myMethod1();" />
```

simply add the line in script below the following line like:

```
console.log("mySpan2");
myMethod();
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd want to create a single function that calls `myMethod1` and/or `myMethod2` based on some condition:

```html
<input
  type="text"
  id="txtDate"
  name="SelectedDate"
  onchange="handleInputChange()"
/>

<span id="mySpan1"></span>
<span id="mySpan2"></span>

<script>
function handleInputChange() {
  var dateVal = new Date(document.getElementById("txtDate").value);
  var dateday = dateVal.getDate();
  
  if (dateday !== 15) {
    myMethod1()
  } else {
    myMethod2()
  }
}

function myMethod1() {
  document.getElementById("mySpan1").innerHTML = "Error Message";
}

function myMethod2() {
  document.getElementById("mySpan2").innerHTML = "No Error";
}
</script>
```