# JavaScript function call interprets encoded Single Quote %27 as literal

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, urlencode, function-call

Requirements:

- I have to `fetch` a URL that contains a single quote.
- I am required to call a function via; e.g. `<a href="javascript:my_function('my_quote%27s.txt');">...</a>`.

After a *lot* of hassle of trying to properly encode a single quote (`%27`) both Waterfox and Chrome *both* keep throwing errors. Chrome allowed me to see that the error was triggered because the browsers are taking it upon themselves to decode strings (when I have *not* programed them to) turning `%27` in to the *literal single quote character* so it errors out before the function is even called (e.g. `my_function('my_quotes's.txt')` with the quote being internally decoded and causing the obvious triple quote issue).

I could use PHP's `htmlentities($file_name, ENT_QUOTES)` though I'd have to string replace `&#039;` which seems pointlessly convoluted.

- I am *required* to support the single quote and make the call via `javascript:`.
- I'd like to avoid literal interpretation of encoded strings when calling functions.
- I'd like to minimize the fuss and just use *an* encoding that JavaScript won't complain about.
- No frameworks or libraries.

How do I properly encode a single quote in a manner that JavaScript won't take it upon itself to somehow internally decode it and throw errors?

Comment: "*I am required to make the call via `javascript:`*" - shudder. Don't. [It's known as a bad practice since over ten years!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479557/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-use-links-with-the-javascript-protocol) And it's exactly what's causing the URL decoding of your script.

Comment: Are you using PHP to generate this html? If you want to use PHP for encoding/escaping the value, please tag your question with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am required to make the call via `javascript:`

Shudder. Please fix this. [It's known as a bad practice since over ten years!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479557/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-use-links-with-the-javascript-protocol) And it's exactly what's causing the URI decoding - the `javascript:` schema is followed by an percent-encoded value to interpret.

So if you start with the js code

```
my_function('my&quote's.txt');
```

it would become one of

```
javascript:my_function%28%27my%26quote%27s.txt%27%29%3B
javascript:my_function(%27my%26quote%27s.txt%27)%3B
javascript:my_function('my%26quote's.txt')%3B
```

(the apostrophe `'` and the parenthesis actually don't need to be encoded).

But `'my_quote's.txt'` is not the valid javascript that you want to start with. What you're actually looking for is `'my_quote\'s.txt'` or `"my_quote's.txt'`. To use these in a `javascript:`-scheme URI, it becomes

```
javascript:my_function('my_quote\'s.txt')%3B
javascript:my_function("my_quote's.txt")%3B
```

So if you generate this `href` string from a dynamic filename value, you must

1. String-escape the filename in the JS string literal
2. URL-encode the complete code in the `javascript` url
3. html-entity-escape the complete `href` attribute value

Answer (score 2):

The value of an `href` a attribute **is** a URL. A `javascript:` scheme URL is a URL.

If you want a `%` to mean “A percent sign” instead of “The start of a percent encoded character” in a URL then you need to URL encode it.

```
...my_quote%2527s.txt...
```

Comment: A quick test reveals that your answer works. So how do I turn `%27` in to `%2527` via PHP?

Comment: I suspect `urlencode` will do it, but I’m not in a position to check.

Comment: `rawurlencode(rawurlencode("'"))` does the trick...a little obnoxious though I'll get it ironed out. Thank you! I'll accept once the timer expires.

Comment: @John But that's most likely wrong. You need to js-escape the string literal.